# Do ViewEngines Impact The Perfomance of Asp.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, performance, razor, spark-view-engine

Last evening i was thinking that there are different view-engines in asp.net mvc like;

```
Spark
Web Forms
Razor
```

(i know the are differed syntactically as well but)

**Do they effect the perfomance of asp.net mvc projects?**

Let's say i would like to use "Razor" instead of Web Froms. So, **will i get the performance hit?** if yes. Please! explain.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your usage of each listed view engines (Spark, Web Forms, Razor) you may get potential performance problems.
Unfortunately, great tool ended to be not properly used, eventually turns to be a problem.

All in all, i will suggest to use the view engine that *you and your team feel more comfortable with.*

Basically, trying to be aware of options and mastering your tool base is the way for productivity and good performance.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, every choice you make in software development will impact performance. However, many choices don't make a noticeable difference.

Do you have a performance problem in your MVC app? Unless you can pinpoint Razor as the performance bottleneck, which is unlikely, don't bother.

Most performance issues in a web application are related to database queries, general network traffic, uncompressed static resources, etc.

Comment: So, it means i shouldn't worry about viewengines anymore.

Comment: Yes, that's the short answer.